# How to enhance csrf protection for existing spring boot and anjularjs application?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, csrf

I need to add csrf protection to my existing spring boot application having angularJS is the client-side framework.

Answer (score 0):

spring-security needs to set the cookie 'XSRF-TOKEN
' but not in HttpOnly. Then angular's javascript will read the cookie and add it to the headers of outgoing http requests.

In your spring-boot codebase there should be a class similar to :

`@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 
    // class content
}`

In this class there should be a chain starting with 'http.'

In this chain add
`.csrf(csrf ->
                csrf
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            )`

From the documentation : "By default the CookieCsrfTokenRepository will write to a cookie named XSRF-TOKEN and read it from a header named X-XSRF-TOKEN or the HTTP parameter _csrf. These defaults come from AngularJS".